# How do I simulate a user cancelling an order in Google Wallet's sandbox?

Tags: in-app-purchase, in-app-billing, google-checkout, android-pay

How do I simulate a user cancelling an order in Google Wallet's sandbox?

I'd like to test the case where a user cancels an order.  Is there a way to do this via the Google Wallet sandbox.

I purchase via a test account and I see the order in my transaction list, but I don't see a way to cancel the order.  I only see a "contact business" link where I can request to cancel the order.

Is this the only way the user can cancel the order?

If there is a user controlled cancel option, can we simulate this in the sandbox?

Answer (score 0):

In the sandbox it may take about 40 minutes for the orders to be "charged".

After that the user will see a "Cancel Subscription" button next to the item description.

Answer (score 0):

you can click to Contac [Seller Name] and send a request to cancel your order right.
The seller may or m
ay not cancel your request.